# Java JFrame freezing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, freeze

I have this simple java application using swing. However the moment I execute the program the frame will appear but I won't be able to click anywhere and the button only appears after a few seconds. I am very new to javas Swing library so I could be missing something, however from what I've read this code shouldn't be causing any issues.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Example");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JLabel label = new JLabel("This is a label!");
        JButton button = new JButton();

        button.setText("Press me");

        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(button);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

**EDIT**
So I reinstalled my jdk but discovered this: if my browser is running when I execute the above code it will hang and freeze, however if I close my browser it runs as expected. But I can't start my browser until I kill my application so it seems something is wrong with my install as these shouldn't be using the same resources?

**EDIT**
Solved my problem: had multiple versions of jdk and jre install so unstalled both and then installed latest versions and everything seems to be working!

Comment: Java version, OS, CPU, RAM ?

Comment: I'm using java 8 on windows 10, i5-6600k and 16gb RAM. However I just realized that even when opening the "About Java" application it lagged in the same way, so it seems my problem is relateds to java in general rather than this specific code.

Comment: should work like u did. I am curious is your frame actually freezing or just butto appears after eg window resizing.

Answer (score 0):

You **need** to create UI under UI dispatching thread:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // code to create UI or call to function that creates the UI
    }
});
```

Java 8 style:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{
    // Your UI code
});
```

If you don't use that idiom then the UI can't be partially created in inconsistent state, see [Creating UI in swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html):

> almost all code that creates or interacts with Swing components must
>   run on the event dispatch thread

You can also use `invokeAndWait` is you need to block until the UI is created.

Comment: downvoting needs some explanation.

Comment: Other than answering a blantant duplicate, this doesn't answer the question. His code works fine for me. You're generalizing, without even being aware of the actual problem.

Comment: I don't downvote, even this is the recomended way, the example runs here without any issues

Comment: @VinceEmigh You're wrong, it **can work** without using this idiom but there is no guarantee, this is a **very** common pitfall among swing users. Please read documentation before claiming it works. Swing is thread-unsafe.

Comment: Doesn't mean he's falling victim to it. Yeah, you should post code to the EDT. But if his window is freezing on every occurrence, do you really think it's an issue revolving around his very simplistic code not being posted to the EDT?

Comment: Yes its symptoms are exactly the consequence of it. Did you read the documentation about this? Surely not.

Comment: Of course I did. I know how Swing works. You obviously don't. Did you even run his code? You generalized. It's not even an inconsistency... Are you aware of *why* we post to the EDT? Or did you not even scratch the surface of that topic

Comment: @VinceEmigh Of course! This code can fail exactly as described. It is very common to fail more frequently on Windows than *nix variants, probably due to the way threads are managed. OP's code is wrong, he needs to correct it.

Comment: Yes, it *can* fail. As in inconsistent, like the documentation specifies. The results here are not inconsistent. And yes, I ran it on Windows quite a few times without being able to reproduce. You're assuming the OP ran it once, then just so happen to be unlucky enough to run into an inconsistency. You saw the lack of `invokeLater` and jumped on it. Yeah, his code isn't perfect, but is your answer the solution? Will that 100% for sure fix his problem?

Comment: Doing as @Jean-BaptisteYunès suggests didn't change anything, my issues seems to be related to using java as I've noticed that any java executable lags when run.

Comment: this answer is totally invalid.

Comment: Ok guys, I agree that this may not be the solution, but starting from an incorrect program anything else cannot be deduced.